# How can make my code to take less time to process?

Tags: excel, vba

Basically I have the following vba code that I apply on 5000+ rows and it takes quite a while and I wanted to know if there was any way to make it run a little bit faster.
I'm basically trying to optimize the values for x and y and running them on every single rows.

Thanks in advance

```
Sub maximise(ByRef x As Range, ByRef y As Range)

    Dim ypos1 As Double, ypos2 As Double, yneg1 As Double, yneg2 As Double
    Dim xpos As Double, xneg As Double

    x = 0.01
    ypos1 = y.Value2
    ypos2 = ypos1

    ActiveSheet.Calculate

    Do While ypos2 - ypos1 >= 0
        ypos1 = y.Value2
        xpos = x.Value2
        x.Value2 = x.Value2 + 0.01
        ActiveSheet.Calculate
        ypos2 = y.Value2
    Loop

    ActiveSheet.Calculate

    x = -0.01
    yneg1 = y.Value2
    yneg2 = yneg1

    ActiveSheet.Calculate

    Do While yneg2 - yneg1 >= 0
        yneg1 = y.Value2
        xneg = x.Value2
        x.Value2 = x.Value2 - 0.01
        ActiveSheet.Calculate
        yneg2 = y.Value2
    Loop

    ActiveSheet.Calculate

    If ypos1 > yneg1 Then
        x.Value2 = xpos
    Else
        x.Value2 = xneg
    End If

    ActiveSheet.Calculate

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried benchmarking your code to find the hotspots?

Comment: I bet it's all the sheet calculations. Maybe if all the calculating was done by VBA instead of in the sheet, the code could run faster. There may also be a better way to find the optimum values you are looking for (impossible to say without knowing what your sheet is calculating) but that may be better asked at the [Math Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Moreover, you're recalculating `ActiveSheet`, but nothing says `x` and `y` are on *that* sheet - all these recalcs might actually have exactly zero effect. You don't *normally* need to recalculate an entire worksheet.

Comment: How many iterations are your loops typically performing?  You might try making your initial step larger, then decrease the step and revisit the tipping point.

Comment: Hijack the Calculation function for the Worksheet.  So you control what is happening / updating.

Answer (score 0):

Without changing your code, you can try turning off screen updating

```
    Sub maximise(ByRef x As Range, ByRef y As Range)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim ypos1 As Double, ypos2 As Double, yneg1 As Double, yneg2 As Double
Dim xpos As Double, xneg As Double

x = 0.01
ypos1 = y.Value2
ypos2 = ypos1

ActiveSheet.Calculate

Do While ypos2 - ypos1 >= 0
   ypos1 = y.Value2
   xpos = x.Value2
   x.Value2 = x.Value2 + 0.01
   ActiveSheet.Calculate
   ypos2 = y.Value2
Loop

ActiveSheet.Calculate

x = -0.01
yneg1 = y.Value2
yneg2 = yneg1

ActiveSheet.Calculate

Do While yneg2 - yneg1 >= 0
   yneg1 = y.Value2
   xneg = x.Value2
   x.Value2 = x.Value2 - 0.01
   ActiveSheet.Calculate
   yneg2 = y.Value2
Loop

ActiveSheet.Calculate

If ypos1 > yneg1 Then
    x.Value2 = xpos
Else
    x.Value2 = xneg
End If

ActiveSheet.Calculate

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```